# On Button click change Button value text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have response form in asp.net. I want on send button click the button text should change from send to please wait & once it is send it should back to it's default value text 'send'. can any one help?

code

```
Protected Sub submit_client_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit_client.Click
        Try
            Dim pattern As String
            pattern = "^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"
            If Regex.IsMatch(TextBox3.Text, pattern) Then
                Label2.Text = ""
            Else
                Label2.Text = "Not a valid Email address "
            End If

            Dim emails As New List(Of String)()

            generate.Visible = True
            clear.Visible = True

            SendHTMLMail()

            'For Each item As ListViewItem In lvCustomers.Items
            '    Dim ck As CheckBox = DirectCast(item.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
            '    If ck.Checked Then
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: you can do using if else {} condition. Please show some code, so that we can help you better

Comment: Try to text change of button before and after `SendHTMLMail()`

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar Please can you be specific by adding answer.

Comment: @NadeemKhan Please give me solution

Comment: @StupidRomeo: dude, can you check my first comment, I already gave you the logic to do. I have some other imp task also. And this is not something which you can't find on the google. I suggest you please do some research and post. It would save the time for both of us. Thanks. :)

Comment: @NadeemKhan you told me "Please show some code, so that we can help you better" & i posted my code then got some other matter replies from you. I am sorry if i misbehaved with you. I am also tying, searching for solution.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
  MyButton.Text="Sending"

  SendHTMLMail()         

  Thread.Sleep(3000)       // add this & remove SendHTMLMail() for testing

  MyButton.Text="Send"
```

Comment: I already tried this earlier but it shows this error (Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Protected Sub submit_client_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.)

Comment: your code works well but after page gets load after button click & that's not something which i want.